# Additional dependencies in XNA/Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, windows-8

I made a game in monogame recently, using the XNA content pipleline. I then sent the whole folder (The release folder in visual studio) to a friend of mine who does not have visual studio or monogame. He said he can't open the game. What the are files I need to give my friend for him to be able to play it?

He has Windows 8

Comment: Does it not give an error message?

Comment: Forgot to ask him. He has not been online for a few days. I will ask him and get back :)

Comment: OpenAL is usually one thing that needs to be installed.

Comment: Ok this is what my friend told me "the game starts but its black can't see a thing... and I hear some music, then a message pops up that says the game has stopped working"
So he needs OpenAL? Is it a dll? What else do I need? Sorry for my noobness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend either need to install all the same develop tools you have (Visual Studio and XNA/Monogame) or you can create an install package. Right click the project and pick publish.

[image]

Then you gill get a wizard. I put mine in E:\Temp

[image]

Next step is simplest if you select CD-ROM or DVD-ROM. You can just as well install from a folder on the hard drive. In my case the files were put in E:\Temp

[image]

Next step it to put all files in that folder in a zip file and send it to your friend for installation.